# Is there a way to activate a transition on click event and not on hover for example?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm struggling in finding a non JS solution for my problem. Is there a way of activate a CSS transition on click and not on :hover or others?

Comment: What do you have so far ? Could you show us your code and the markup as well ?

Comment: There is nothing to try in this case, you just need to know which CSS rule to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility: You can add a class that holds the transition on click. This is an example using jQuery - you can also achieve this programmatically using "raw" JavaScript only:

**HTML container that should be animated**

```
<div id="transtion"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// bind click event to the element itself - but it can also be any other element that triggers this …
$('#transition').click(function() {
    // add the classname thats defined with the transition in your CSS
    $(this).addClass('translate_left');
});
```

Comment: Isn't there some synta error with the `=.click`?

Comment: @TomášZato Yeah - already corrected that - I'm typing on an English keyboard which has a different layout than my default one. :)

Comment: I know that feeling bro... :D Anyway, I'm not sure if using jQuery is what the asker wanted, thoug your solution is nice and clear. Mind that jQuery is javascript too.

Comment: @TomášZato Haha of course it is. As I tried to say, it's only an example for jQuery but it can be done easily without any JavaScript library. :)

Comment: Haha, After re-reading the question I found that it was asked for a none JavaScript solution. Absolutely overlooked this. But it's not really possible doing it without JavaScript.

Comment: Well, my solution works, but the efect only persists for the time the button is held down. Asker does not like that.

Answer (score -1):

There is [pseudoclass](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-pseudo-classes/) for click too. But it has somewhat strange name, and normally it is only know as related to HTML link styling.

```
DIV.button:active {
   border-style: inset;
}
```

[Here is some nice example.](http://u8.8u.cz//crap/moz-transition.html)

Comment: i want only 1 click. i don't want to keep click pressed.

Comment: Then you need to use javascript - there must be something that remembers that the object was clicked. In that case, you shouldn've voted down, because you didn't specify this in your question. This is the non-javascript solution you originally asked for.